Group automorphism fixing finite-index subgroup
Let $\tau \colon G \rightarrow G$ be an automorphism of a finitely generated torsion-free group $G$ that fixes a normal subgroup $H \lhd G$ of finite-index. Must $\tau$ have finite order? I am mainly interested in the case where $H$ is Abelian, but I haven't been able to make much progress in this situation either.
Edit: I meant to say fixes pointwise, i.e. that $\tau|_H$ is the identity homomorphism.

Can't you drop down to $G/H$ and find a finite order there?

So you mean $\tau\restriction_H$ is the identity homomorphism.

Thanks, edited.

As @SteveD says, doesn't $\tau$ correspond to an automorphism of $G/H$? This certainly has finite order since $\mathrm{Aut}(G/H)$ has finite order right?

That doesn't seem clear to me. A power of $\tau$ fixes the cosets, but I don't see why it should fix them pointwise

It reduces the problem to the case when $\tau$ induces the identity on $G/H$.

Making a small change to a comment left by @tkf yields a negative answer.
Let $G = \langle a,b \mid aba = b \rangle$, i.e. the fundamental group of the Klein bottle. This group is finitely generated and torsion-free, so fits your criteria. Let $H = \langle a,b^2 \rangle$, which is an abelian subgroup of index 2 (hence normal).
Let $\tau$ be the automorphism defined by $\tau(a) = a$, $\tau(b) = ba$. Then also $\tau(b^2) = (ba)^2 = b^2$, so $\tau$ fixes $H$ pointwise. But $\tau^k(b) = ba^k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, so $\tau$ has infinite order.

(+1) After I made the comment I realised I just needed to drop the second relation to get rid of the torsion and everything else would still work.  Only just got a chance to log in - well done for getting there first.


Let $G$ be a group and let $H \unlhd G$ be a normal subgroup of finite index. The following statements are equivalent:

There exists an automorphism $\tau \in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ of infinite order such that $\tau$ fixes $H$.
There exists an automorphism $\tau \in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ of infinite order such that $\tau$ fixes $H$ and induces the trivial automorphism $\tilde{\tau} \in \mathrm{Aut}(G/H)$.
There exists an automorphism $\tau \in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ of infinite order such that $\tau(g) = [g, h]g$ for some $h \in Z(H)$.
There exists $h \in H$ of infinite order such that $N = C_G(\langle h \rangle)$ is an index $2$ normal subgroup of $G$ with $H \leqslant N \leqslant G$.


$(1) \Leftrightarrow (2)$. The reverse implication is clear. For the forward implication, observe that $K = G/H$ is a finite group, so $\mathrm{Aut}(K)$ is also a finite group. Thus, replacing $\tau$ with $\tau^{|\mathrm{Aut}(K)|}$, we see that $\tilde{\tau}$ acts trivially on $K$.
$(2) \Leftrightarrow (3)$. The reverse implication is clear. For the forward implication, define the set-theoretic map $f: G \to H$ given by $f(g) := \tau(g)g^{-1}$. Observe the following properties of $f$:

We have $f(g_1g_2) = f(g_1)f(g_2)^{g_1}$, since: $$f(g_1g_2)g_1g_2 = \tau(g_1g_2) = \tau(g_1)\tau(g_2) = f(g_1)g_1f(g_2)g_2 = f(g_1)f(g_2)^{g_1}g_1g_2$$
$f(gH) = f(g)$ since $f(gh)gh = \tau(gh) = \tau(g)\tau(h) = \tau(g)h = f(g)gh$.
$\mathrm{im} f \subseteq A = Z(H)$ by the above formulae since $f(g_2)^{g_1}$ only depends on $g_1 \bmod H$.

Thus, we may interpret $f$ as a set-theoretic map $K \to A$ satisfying $f(k_1k_2) = f(k_1)f(k_2)^{k_1}$. In other words, $f$ is a $1$-cocycle corresponding to the $K$-module $A$. Furthermore, one may check that composing automorphisms on $G$ sums the corresponding $1$-cocycles. Since the cohomology group $H^1(K; A)$ is killed by $|K|$, after replacing $f$ with $|K|f$, we see that $f$ must be a $1$-coboundary. This means we have $h \in A$ such that $f(g) = h^{g-1}$, so $\tau(g) = h^{g-1}g = [g, h]g$.
$(3) \Leftrightarrow (4)$. For the forward implication, observe that $\ker \tau = N$. Since $H \leqslant \ker \tau$, we have $H \leqslant N \leqslant G$. Furthermore, $G/N$ acts faithfully on $\langle h \rangle$ by conjugation. Since $\mathrm{Aut}(\langle h\rangle) = \mathbb{Z}/2$ and $N \lneq G$, we must have $[G:N] = 2$. Finally, $h$ has infinite order since $\tau^n(g) = h^{-2n}g$ for $g \not \in N$ implies that $h^{-2n} \neq 1$ for all positive integers $n$.
For the reverse direction, we have $h \in Z(H)$ since $H \leqslant N$. Consider the map $\tau(g) := [g, h]g$, we shall first show that $\tau$ is an automorphism. Note that $[g, h] = h^{g-1}$ is equal to $1$ and $h^{-2}$ when $g \in N$ and $g \not \in N$ respectively. It is clear from this that $\tau$ is a bijection. Now:

If $g_1, g_2 \in N$, then $\tau(g_1g_2) = g_1g_2 = \tau(g_1)\tau(g_2)$.
If $g_1 \in N$ and $g_2 \not \in N$, then $\tau(g_1g_2) = h^{-2}g_1g_2 = g_1h^{-2}g_2 = \tau(g_1)\tau(g_2)$.
If $g_1 \not \in N$ and $g_2 \in N$, then $\tau(g_1g_2) = h^{-2}g_1g_2 = \tau(g_1)\tau(g_2)$.
If $g_1, g_2 \not \in N$, then $\tau(g_1g_2) = g_1g_2 = h^{-2}(h^{-2})^{g_1}g_1g_2 = h^{-2}g_1h^{-2}g_2 = \tau(g_1)\tau(g_2)$.

Thus, $\tau$ is indeed an automorphism. Finally, $\tau$ has infinite order since $\tau^n(g) = h^{-2n}g$ for $g \not \in N$.

Now, the obvious construction for a counterexample is $G = \mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ with $H = N = \mathbb{Z} \rtimes 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $h = (1, 0)$. This is precisely the counterexample given by @sTertooy (which is in turn motivated by the example given by @tkf where $G$ is the infinite dicyclic group).

Where does your argument use that $G$ has no torsion?  The statement fails if $G$ is allowed to have torsion: If $G=\langle a,b|,, aba=b, b^2=1\rangle$ and $H$ is the index $2$ subgroup $H={a^k|,, k\in \mathbb{Z}}$.  Let $\tau\colon a\mapsto a,\tau\colon b\mapsto ba$.  Then $\tau$ fixes $H$, and induces the identity map on $G/H$, but has infinite order.

@tkf Thank you for pointing that out! I have edited my answer now, but it isn't a complete answer anymore. I'll keep thinking about it :)
